# Typescript Class as a Member Variable in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm learning Angular and TypeScript and I have a question or two.

With TypeScript can you have one class/object be the variable type for an other object as shown below? If so how do you reference the all of the members using Angular.

```
/* begin cmsfiles.ts */

export class CMSFiles {
  fileID: number;
  fileDateTime: Date;
  fileName: string;
  description: string;
}
/* end cmsfiles.ts */

/* begin news.ts */

import { CMSFiles } from './cmsfiles';

export class News {
  newsID: number;
  postDateTime: Date;
  title: string;
  body: string;
  file1: CMSFiles;
  file2: CMSFiles;
}
/* end news.ts */
```

In the Angular template I will need to use something like this:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="news.file1.Title" placeholder="title" />
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: The field `Title` doesn't exist on `CMSFiles`. Did you mean `fileName`?

Comment: Yes, you are correct I do mean fileName and not title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes define types. Those types can be used wherever any of the default types can be used.

In short yes.

Comment: do you know if  <input [(ngModel)]="news.file1.fileName" placeholder="fileName" /> is correct syntax?

Comment: if the properties of the CMSFiles class are public yes. :) It's just normal js notation